# Atom editor, cannot open file with ":" in name

Tags: atom-editor

I have a problem with atom, when trying to open a file.
File name pattern is:

> `name_dd.MM.YYYY_hh:ss`

Where: `dd.MM.YYYY` denotes the date and `hh:ss` the time of file creation. Now, whenI try to open it, either from terminal or directly from atom, instead of showing the content of the file, atom creates a new temporary empty file named:

> `name_dd.MM.YYYY_hh`

Seems like atom is having trouble recognizing the full file name and truncates it right after ":". There is no problem when opening this file with gedit or nano. Anyone knows what might be causing the problem? I know I can just change the naming pattern, but now I am genuinely curious what is causing this weird behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which operating system do you use? How do you open the file (e.g. from the command line)? For interoperability, I recommend not using colons since they are reserved characters on some operating systems / file systems ([details on Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Filename#/Reserved_characters_and_words)).

Comment: I use Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS. I tried to open it both from command line and from atom itself with no luck. I had no problem when opening using nano or gedit (from command line). On the page you provided it does not state ":" is used by linux like operating systems.

Comment: Opening file with a colon works just fine on macOS. That is, unless the file-system does some tricks handling those file-names. When I view the file in Finder (the macOS window manager), the file is displayed with forward-slash in place of a colon. In Terminal, it's displayed with a colon.

Anyway, it might be a Linux-specific bug and should be reported on the [Atom repository](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues).